# Django Postgres ArrayField __contain lookup does not behave expectedly

Tags: python, django

This is my *models.py*:

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I did this in the django shell:

```
Dog.objects.create(name='Rufus', data={ 'breed': 'labrador', 'owner': { 'name': 'Bob', 'other_pets': [{  'name': 'Fishy',  }], }, })
Dog.objects.create(name='Meg', data={'breed': 'collie'})
Dog.objects.filter(data__breed__contains='l')
```

However when I did the last command it gave me an empy queryset return:

```
<QuerySet []>
```

The two objects *(Meg and Rufus)* should have both returned because they both contain l

This is my query:

```
SELECT "post_tagging_dog"."id", "post_tagging_dog"."name", "post_tagging_dog"."data" FROM "post_tagging_dog" WHERE "post_tagging_dog"."data" -> 'breed' @> '"l"'
```

Comment: Have you examined the generated SQL?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I updated my question

Comment: Smells like a bug. I *think* the correct condition should be `'l' IN "post_tagging_dog"."data" -> 'breed'`, but I have no experience with PostgreSQL's JSON support.

Comment: The [`@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) checks if the left json contains the path/value entries from the right json. So JSONField's `contains` is not the correct one to use here. You need to get the `breed` values as text and check if those contain the letter `l`. Not sure how you do this with Django's ORM.

Comment: @Sevanteri, so what is the proper query for this one?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada You can get the string value from JSON with `->>`. So you could check the content of the string with `LIKE` or regex (`~*`) or their case insensitive versions `ILIKE` and `~*`: `... WHERE "post_tagging_dog"."data" ->> 'breed' ~ 'l';`

Answer (score -1):

try simply `for + if`:

```
for obj in Dog.objects:
    if 'l' in obj.data['breed']:
        return obj
```